# Implement automatic version self-check and update in a PHP script with github

Tags: php, git, github

Now that the code for [a small RSS-reading CMS](http://github.com/xaccrocheur/nws) that I've done is hosted on github, I'd like it to

- check automatically if there is a newer version of itself's in the master branch
- Allow the user to update said script, ie it would overwrite itself with the newer version

Comment: So what is the problem you're having?

Comment: ? Well I don't know where to start ! How do you (I) do that ? Is there a PHP function for that ? 
Is there a github API function for that ? 
Is it even possible ?

I have this page, index.php, on a server A.
And the same page, index.php, on the server B, only newer.

What do I put in serverA/index.php to check for the version of serverB/index.php ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is [what I came up with](https://github.com/xaccrocheur/nws/blob/master/index.php) (thanks to [cillosis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/468592/cillosis)'s answer)

```
$commits = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.github.com/repos/user_name/repository_name/commits"));

$current_commit_minus1 = $commits[1]->sha;
$ref_commit = "57b75c0f8aefa5ce87c1270265cace18a2347594";

if (!strcmp($current_commit_minus1, $ref_commit))
    $moved = true;
  else
    $moved = false;
```

That way I don't have to maintain tags, just compare commits.

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible maintaining a current version number within the script, and then comparing it to the repository using the [Repositories API](http://developer.github.com/).

You can get repo tags with CURL like this (replace :user and :repo with your stuff):

`curl http://github.com/api/v2/json/repos/show/:user/:repo/tags`

You can show branches like this:

`curl http://github.com/api/v2/json/repos/show/:user/:repo/branches`

There is a lot of other info available in that API as well.

Once you get that, compare it to the current and procede with updating.

Comment: The command that worked for me : `curl https://api.github.com/repos/user_name/repository_name/tags`